# Windows Form Login

Tags: winforms, security

What is the easiest way to remember a users details within a winform application.

Basically I have an application which requires a login. How do I hold a session like value within the application so I can easily query who is logged in etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's more info on this subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348545.aspx